# problems trying to add a date/timestamp to output files in perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to add a datestamp to my output files using perl. What I'm getting is a strange '?' appended to the time stamp for a logfile.

Output file: `abcdump-20110120?.log`

And the other strange behavior is that my code won't name my output file with a .csv extension where I am using my `$dt` (date) variable `$node-$tblist.$dt.csv`

Output file: `foo-p000.20110120`

But, If I remove `$dt` from the naming convention `$node-$tblist.csv`

it will work: `foo-p000.csv`

It must be how I am trying to create my datestamp.

Code:

```
    my $dt =  `date '+%Y%m%d'`;
    open (LOG, "> abcdump-$dt.log") || die "cannot append";
    foreach my $tblist (@tblist)
    {
       chomp $tblist;   
       my $crfile = qq{mysql -u test -pf00 --database $dbsrc -h $node -ss -e "SELECT 'a','b','c' UNION SELECT 1,2,3 FROM $tblist"| tr "\t" ",">$node-$tblist.$dt.csv};
       system($crfile); 
       print LOG "Executed on $dt => $crfile\n";
    };
    close(LOG);
```

Comment: You should probably investigate `time` and `strftime` (from POSIX module) and `localtime` so you don't go running the `date` command. Approximately: `my $dt = strftime('+%Y%m%d', localtime(time));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring the other issues in your code, I suspect it's a newline as part of the `date` output.

```
chomp $dt;
```

should take care of both of the problems you describe.

You may also wish to consider using Perl's `localtime` or `gmtime` instead.

Comment: thanks! yes, chomp cleaned that up. works fine now. will consider your input for localtime.